# How to sync a server with bitbucket automatically

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

Is it possible that when I push to a repo on Bitbucket, it automatically updates my server too?

Currently I push to a repo. then login into my server. and pull from repo.

since the server is Linux, can  I create a script with commands like `git pull` which runs every 5 minutes or so?

Comment: found a link http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2013/11/19/automated-git-deployments-from-bitbucket/

Answer (score 1):

You can't really pull automatically, but you can do notifications.

For example via webhooks: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html

But an easier solution is probably to just push to both places yourself. You can set up [multiple push remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849308/pull-push-from-multiple-remote-locations) for example. Then if you want to update the code automatically, you can set it up using [git hooks/triggers](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks).

Comment: can it be done by running a script with command git pull every 5 minutes or so?

Comment: yeah, right.. How about not using bitbucket, and directly push to the server?

Comment: That's the third paragraph